# Child element appearing AFTER as opposed to IN the element when appended using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I am appending the following using jQuery:

```
var dateWrapper = '<p class="date">'+kendo.format('{0:dd MMMM yyyy}',new Date(date))+'<div class="triangle"></div></p>'
$('.wrapper').append(dateWrapper)
```

I want the triangle to appear inline or inline-block with the date. Once appended the DIV is placed after the P, and not inside. Cannot fathom why this would happen.

Comment: From the given code, others will have a tough time fathoming it too. Please provide more code, especially your `date` and `triangle` classes. Also, `div` is by default `position:block`, so set it to `inline-block` if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the HTML5 documentation ( and as far as i know it's the same for older versions ) , `p` accepts as children only `pharsing content`

[p element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/grouping-content.html#the-p-element)

`Pharsing content` means plain text or `pharsing elements` which include `<a>`,`</span>`,`<strong>` etc. but not `<div>`

[pharsing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#phrasing-content-2)

So a structure like `<p><div></div></p>` is not a valid HTML5 structure, so it is automatically converted into `<p></p><div></div><p></p>` .

In conclusion you CAN NOT nest `div` inside `p` and that's why you don't get the desired result. I suggest, in your case, change the triangle from div to span

Answer (score 3):

You can not put div inside p tag. It will automatically put it outside the p tag. You should use..

```
var dateWrapper = '<p class="date">'+kendo.format('{0:dd MMMM yyyy}',new Date(date))+'<span class="triangle"></span></p>';
$('.wrapper').append(dateWrapper);
```

### In css

```
.triangle{
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: `Span` elements are already `display: inline` by default, no need for extra CSS.